# Move all elements if move stroll listview

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview, listviewitem

I have a problem with the items, when I move the list, it also moves the part arrives, that makes up space on the screen, I want it to go away when the list to move and to appear when the stroll is in the part of arrives, thank you very much! Sorry for the translation but is cast with a translator.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.app.flyforo.MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/contentUser"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:background="@drawable/banner" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageUser"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/userName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:text="Flyforo"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="11sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/userTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="28dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Flyforo"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/contentSeguidores"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/contentUser" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.74"
            android:background="#FBFBFB"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/numseguidores"
                android:layout_width="215dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="4"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="215dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Seguidores"
                android:textSize="13sp" />

        </LinearLayout>



    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/contentSeguidores"
        >





        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/border2"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/buttoninicio"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Inicio"
                android:textSize="17sp" />

        </LinearLayout>






        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/border2"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/buttonposts"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:text="Posts" />

        </LinearLayout>











    </LinearLayout>


<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/loading"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:indeterminate="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/contentUser"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_add_person"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:background="@drawable/button_confirm"
        android:text="" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/profileList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/menu"
         >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you mean you have content *above* the ListView, and when you scroll the ListView, you want the content that's above it to scroll off the screen too. If this is describes your issue, continue reading!

You'll want to wrap the content above the ListView in its own XML file, inflate it as a single ViewGroup, and then add that ViewGroup as a header on the ListView.

### Separating your layout into ListView and HeaderView

Your view hierarchy looks as follows:

```
RelativeLayout
    LinearLayout=contentUser
    LinearLayout=contentSeguidores
    LinearLayout=menu
    ProgressBar
    Button
    ListView
/RelativeLayout
```

If this is in a file called `activity_list.xml`, then you can copy the contents to another file called `view_list_header.xml` in your layout directory. In this copied file, delete the ListView, and in `activity_list.xml` delete everything except the ListView, so that the file structures will be as follows:

`activity_list.xml`:

```
<ListView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/profileList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

and `view_list_header.xml`:

```
RelativeLayout
    LinearLayout=contentUser
    LinearLayout=contentSeguidores
    LinearLayout=menu
    ProgressBar
    Button
/RelativeLayout
```

### Inflating the HeaderView and attaching to the ListView

In your Activity, or wherever you set up your ListView, you will have had something similar to:

```
...
setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.profileList);
listView.setAdapter(...);
...
```

Now, you will need to inflate the header, and add it to ListView *before* setting your adapter:

```
...
setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.profileList);
View headerView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.view_header_list, listView, false);
listView.addHeaderView(headerView);
listView.setAdapter(...);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't sure exactly what you wanted. But I changed the Layout to a linear layout. Then made some extra changes.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                tools:context="com.app.flyforo.MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/contentUser"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            >

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageUser"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/userName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:text="Flyforo"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="11sp" />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/userTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-40dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="28dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="Flyforo"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/contentSeguidores"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/contentUser" android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1">
            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/numseguidores"
                    android:layout_width="215dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="4"
                    android:textSize="17sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="215dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Seguidores"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/contentUser"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"

                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#fff"

                android:text="" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/menu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/contentSeguidores"
            >


        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/buttoninicio"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Inicio"
                android:textSize="17sp" android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/buttonposts"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:text="Posts" android:layout_weight="1"/>


    </LinearLayout>


    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/profileList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/menu"
            >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```